# Memory allocation in looping variable declaration

Tags: c++

case 1:

```
int main()
{
    int T=5;
    while(T--){
        int a;
        cout<<&a<<"\n";
    }
}
```

it prints the same address 5 times.
i suppose it should print 5 different addresses.

case 2:

```
int main()
{
    int T=5;
    while(T--){
        int* a=new int;
        cout<<a<<"\n";
    }
}
```

prints 5 different addresses

My question is:
Why does'nt new memory is allocated every time a variable declaration is encountered in first case?
and the difference between 1st case and 2nd case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, `a` is located on the stack. Basically, `a` gets "constructed" (a better wording might be "assigned space") there in each iteration and released afterwards. So after each iteration, the space previously allocated to `a` is free again, and the new `a` gets that space in the next iteration. This is why the address is the same.

In the second case, you allocate memory on the heap and (additionally) do not free it again. So the memory can't be reassigned in the next iteration.

Comment: And in the second case the allocated memory is leaked, so it *has* to get a new address each time

Comment: @BoPersson right, the second case was added after my answer. Included it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the absolute position on the stack is allocated every time the variable comes into scope and deallocated every time it goes out of scope.  The LIFO nature of the stack in which it is allocated then makes sure the same location is allocated each time.

But in practice, the compiler allocates relative positions on the stack at compile time whenever doing so is practical (which in this case is trivially true).  With pre allocated relative positions, the simple act of entering the function effectively allocates all instances of all local variables.  A local object in a loop like that would be constructed and/or initialized for each instance, but allocation was done once in advance for all instances.  So the addresses are the same for an even more fundamental reason than the LIFO nature of a stack.  They are the same because the allocation was only done once.

If your C++ compiler supports a common C99 feature, you could construct tests that might distinguish the above two cases.  Something roughly like:

```
for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
   int unpredictable[ f(i) ];
   for (int j=0; j<2; ++j) {
      int T=5;
      // does the location of T vary as i changes ??
      int U[ f(j) ];  // I'm pretty sure the location of U varies
}}
```

We want the values of f(0) and f(1) to be easy at run time, but hard for the optimizer to see at compile time.  That is most robust if f is declared in this module but defined in another.

By preventing the compiler from doing all the allocation at compile time, **maybe** we prevent it from doing some easy allocation at compile time, or maybe it still sorts out the ones that can be allocated at compile time and run time allocation is used only as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler. Since the variable is declared in the innermost scope, the compiler thinks it is okay to reuse the same location for the variable. Of course it can be located in different addresses.

Comment: In theory it could depend on the compiler.  But in practice it almost certainly couldn't.  The local allocation is inside a loop, so it would be very difficult for the compiler to not reuse the same location and all that difficulty would serve zero purpose.

Comment: @JSF Yes. I mean the compiler doesn't have to reuse the address, although it reuses it most of the time.